# Parse JSON in React JS from Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm new to React JS and just start working on a project with React JS as frontend and Python Flask 2.2.2 as the backend. In Flask I'm trying to return a JSON in a function:

```
@app.route('/profile')
def test():
    response_body = {
        "test123": "123",
        "name": "Owen!",
        "about": "about!"
    }
    print(f"response is {response_body}")
    return Response(response_body, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Basically, it will just return a JSON object(Flask will automatically convert it to JSON as I learned). And then in JS I used axios to call the backend and get the response like this:

```
axios
            .get("/profile")
            .then(response =>
                console.log(response.data.about)
            )
            .catch(error => {});
```

I also did some research that axios and JS will automatically convert the JSON to Javascript object so "response.data.about" should give me the result in JSON returned from Flask. But I'm actually getting undefined in console.
Could anyone please point me to where it is wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing to do here is often to find out when/where the unexpected behaviour occurs. In this scenario a good starting point would be to find out if this is happening on the client or server. Open up the "Network" tab in the browser development tools. Does the request reach the server? Is the response successful? Does the response contain the expected body and content-type header?

Comment: @3limin4t0r, Thanks for your comment, it did reach the backend server and I mentioned those below. But I think it will be more clear if I mention it in the quesetion itself also.  I will mention more details in my further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your server and your client aren't running on the same port so you need fetch to the actual route of the flask backend

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/profile")
     .then(response => console.log(response.data.about))
     .catch(error => {});
```

Replace that `8080` with the port your backend is running on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the backend and frontend are actually connected, I can see the backend log from Python whenever I clicked the button.

Answer (score 0):

After I changed the return type in Python from

```
return Response(response_body, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

to directly return the body

```
return response_body
```

Then I can get the json value directly: response.data.test123. Not clear for the reason, but will look more into this.